# PySerial doesn’t seem to work when sending data from Raspberry Pi 4 to Mac

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot, pyserial, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to send command (in the form of bytes) from a Raspberry Pi 4 to a Mac using serial connection.

I connected the Pi to my Mac with the scheme specified here: (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/connect-the-lead). Basically, I am using a cable from Prolific Technology to connect the Mac with the UART pins on the Pi.

The default Linux serial console is disabled on the Pi, according to the instructions here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

On both ends, PySerial is used. Mac side reads while Pi writes.

What I see is that both sides keep timing out and Mac never read any bytes.

Source code for the Pi side:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports
from time import sleep

ports = list_ports.comports()

for port in ports:
    print(port)

if len(ports) == 0:
    print("Couldn't find any ports")
    exit(1)

# For now we only expect one port to be available
host_port = ports[0]

print("Found host port: {}".format(host_port.device))

ser = serial.Serial(
    host_port.device, 
    9600, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1,
    write_timeout=1,
)

while True:
    print("writing")
    try:
        ser.write(b'hello')
    except:
        print("Write timeout. Continue...")
    sleep(2)
```

Source code for the Mac side:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports
from time import sleep

ports = list_ports.comports()
robot_port = None

for port in ports:
    if port.manufacturer is not None and "Prolific Technology" in port.manufacturer:
        robot_port = port
        break

if robot_port is None:
    print("Couldn't find an attached worldlike robot")
    exit(1)

print("robot_port: {}".format(robot_port.device))

ser = serial.Serial(robot_port.device, 9600, timeout=10)

if ser is None:
    print("Failed to create serial port")
    exit(1)

while True:
    print("reading")    
    line = ser.read(5)
    print("Read: {}".format(line))
    sleep(2)
```

Output from Pi:

```
/dev/ttyAMA0 - ttyAMA0
Found host port: /dev/ttyAMA0
writing
Write timeout. Continue...
writing
Write timeout. Continue...
…
```

Output from Mac:

```
robot_port: /dev/cu.usbserial-14310
reading
Read: b''
reading
Read: b''
…
```

Any idea why this is?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have a scope, an LED, or some other indicator that would show that the state on the line is changing?  Even a multimeter's min/max mode might work to prove that somebody is transmitting.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure because I don't have a Pi 4 right now but here's my two cents:

There is something wrong with the UART on your Pi or its configuration. When I run your (Pi) code on several embedded devices I have this is what I got:

```
Found host port: /dev/ttyXXXX
writing
writing
....
```

So you are getting an exception. Now I'm getting into guessing mode but I think you are not targeting the port you should.

According to the [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) you posted (see table right under *Linux devices on Raspberry Pi OS*):`/dev/ttyAMA0`is the first PL011 (UART0).

On the same link, read under *Configuration*: the first PL011 (UART0) for a Pi 4 is the secondary (Bluetooth) device.

Finally, under the *Secondary UART* title you'll find this statement:

> The secondary UART is not normally present on the GPIO connector. By default, the secondary UART is connected to the Bluetooth side of the combined wireless LAN/Bluetooth controller, on models which contain this controller.

Conclusion: you should not be trying to access `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

The problem is `list_ports.comports()` does not seem to be giving you the port names as it should. There were some [issues](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=260463) with this, I guess you might be facing something similar.

The quick and headache-free fix is to address your port directly as `/dev/serial0`. If you have time you can dig into the problem and fix how the ports are listed.